# How does `flask run` know where to find my app code in a virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

I'm using `flask` and `virtualenv`, and I have an app directory tree that looks like this:

```
app/
|__app/
|__app.egg-inf/
|__setup.py
|__venv/
```

My `setup.py` is fairly standard. I'm running `pip install -e .` inside my `venv`, which install `flask` and all my other dependencies defined in `.setup.py`. After that I set the environment variable `FLASK_APP=app` so that Flask knows which app I want to run.

My question is, how does `flask run` know where my app is?

The environment variable doesn't specify the path and I couldn't the path to my project's root directory anywhere in there as well. I could navigate to `/tmp` and still type `flask run` and it would find my app, so it's not using my current directory to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It just imports it, and Python (which does the import) [scans](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching) known locations including global packages, local (for virtual env) packages and PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

`flask` takes the module name you provide as `FLASK_APP` and [imports it](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/ed1f6047271dc7ba1ee9c82e0c257b8ac406e80c/flask/cli.py#L183-L209) -- the magic is in the `__import__` builtin.

It knows how to find your application from the module name you provided because you've installed it (via `pip install -e .`).  This adds a `.pth` file in the `site-packages` directory which causes your module to be importable.